# How can I reuse a ci-build in multiple repositories?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project that contains multiple repositories for various NuGet packages. I have a build that gets triggered by changes to the master.

However, I need to create a clone of this build for each repository, even though every build is exactly same just pointing to a different repository.

This means that if I need to change something in the build (except the tasks, since they are in a task group) I'll need to edit every single one of the clones.

I looked around in the marketplace and I could not find a solution to this.

In the case of triggers and branches, you can use filters to include/exclude branches/expressions that trigger the build.
Is there a way to do this with repositories and make the "Get Sources" step "dynamic" or any other solution to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I could not find a sense in having multiple repositories if you have the exact same code. Multiple branches OK. So, just to clarify and try to help. Is the multi repo really necessary? As far as I know there is nothing out of the box to solve it.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang Hey, Rodrigo. I don't have the exact same code, they just build the same way. Most (if not all) of my NuGet packages go through the exact same build process, which results in clones of the build definitions but pointing to different repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for you is to use the YAML builds which is currently in preview?

[How to use YAML builds](https://go.beeming.net/2DU2PL3)

The feature is currently in preview and can be enabled as shown in the below link

[Enable preview features](https://go.beeming.net/2I4QJkC)

In short when logged in click on your profile, then Preview fetures

[image]

Change the level to for this account and then enable Build YAML definitions

[image]

It basically let's you have a yaml file that is your build definition.

Comment: Hey, considering the missing features and limitations on the YAML builds (at least for now) it does not really solve my problem, but I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thank you!

Comment: I'll mark it as an answer if nobody comes up with anything better soon, btw.